# How can I create automatically indexed variables

Tags: r, variables

I need to know how can I create in R **indexed variables** in a data.frame.

Example: I have P1, P2, P3, B1, B2, B3 numeric variables in a data.frame (`dat`) and I have to create the new variables: I1=P1/B1, I2=P2/B2 and I3=P3/B3 in the data.frame `dat` **using a for loop**.

Maybe I was not clear, sorry. I have to create variables (100) Ik, And I don't want to write:

```
dat$I1<-dat$P1/dat$B1  
dat$I2<-dat$P2/dat$B2
dat$I3<-dat$P3/dat$B3    
...
dat$I99<-dat$P99/dat$B99
dat$I100<-dat$P100/dat$B100
```

It's surely possible to do something like that:

```
for(k in 1:100) {
    ???
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't do this with a `for` loop. If you like `for` loops, you should use a different language.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I did give you an answer already, but for the future: Please read the info about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Also share any code that you’ve tried so far. This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the following code to create your new variables:

```
# creating a example dataframe
dat <- data.frame(P1=rnorm(100,40,4), P2=rnorm(100,20,2), P3=rnorm(100,10,1),
                  B1=rnorm(100,10,2), B2=rnorm(100,5,1), B3=rnorm(100,2.5,1))

# creating the new variables
dat$I1 <- dat$P1/dat$B1
dat$I2 <- dat$P2/dat$B2
dat$I3 <- dat$P3/dat$B3
```

---

EDIT: extending on @agstudy's answer:

```
# creating a new dataframe based on @agstudy's
nn <- colnames(dat)
i123 <- mapply(function(x,y)dat[,x]/dat[,y],grep('P',nn),grep('B',nn))
i123 <- as.data.frame(i123)
colnames(i123) <- c("I1","I2","I3")

# adding the dataframe with the new variables to the existing dataframe
dat <- cbind(dat,i123)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could do it easily with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, c("I1", "I2", "I3") := list(P1/B1, P2/B2, P3/B3)]
```

Comment: ouh, +1 for mentioning `setDT`, something I have completely overlooked.

Answer (score 1):

In R , we try to avoid using `for` loops essentially because of their side effect. You should use the R way to do things like:

- Using vectorized operations
- Using one of many `xxapply` family functions

For example , here using `mapply`, I get a generalised version of @Jaap answer:

```
nn <- colnames(dat)
mapply(function(x,y)dat[,x]/dat[,y],grep('P',nn),grep('B',nn))
```

PS: there are some situations where we have no choice and we use a `for loop`, specially where there are some recursion relation between iterations.